# Attaching DOM event handler from a service

Tags: angular, typescript, dom, dependency-injection, angular-services

The current practice for attaching a DOM event handler is to use [`Renderer2.listen()`](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#listen) in case you need to do so not from a template. This approach works great with `Directive`s \ `Component`s.

If you need to do the same in a `Service`, an issue would be that an attempt to inject a `Renderer2` instance into the service constructor:

```
export class SomeService {
    public constructor(private readonly renderer: Renderer2) {
    }
}
```

would lead to a missing DI provider exception:

> StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[DefaultValueAccessor -> Renderer2]

To alleviate it, we could use [`RendererFactory2`](https://angular.io/api/core/RendererFactory2) class to:

> Creates and initializes a custom renderer that implements the
>   Renderer2 base class.

But I'm not sure if creating a new `Render2` for the case of using it in a service is a good\recommended approach.

So, the question is what is the recommended practice for attaching a DOM event handler in a service?

Comment: What exactly is your use case? You shouldn't have to do it in a service.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz Could you expand on why we shouldn't attach a DOM event handler in a service as a general rule(?), please? My specific use case is that I need  to manipulate (attach\detach) a global DOM event handler on the `body` element, in this case to handle bubbling `focusin` events.

Comment: Well basically that's not the purpose of a service. A service doesn't have anything to do with the DOM. What's wrong with having a directive or component handling that? You know your root component can have the selector `body`, and then you can do it in your `AppComponent`, for example. (You don't have to change the selector come to think of it since you're not going to use HostListener).

Comment: @Chrillewoodz You're right, it's better to do it in a `Directive` in this specific case. However, I wouldn't do it in `AppComponent` (even though mine actually has `body` selector already as you've pointed out), since that would be a mixing of concerns into a one entity. So, you've left me without any good use case for attaching a DOM handler in a service :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others have commented that this behavior might be more apt for a `Component` or a `Directive`, but it's fun to see what's happening in Angular at a lower level. This is a very modular framework, and this is a good opportunity to learn more about DI under the hood.

The `Renderer2` is a little special when it comes to services, as it has more control when it comes to *templates* via the internal `Renderer2Interceptor`. It also has a different *scope* than providers injected at the root level or other global Angular providers: since it's used to render the templates of components and directives, it's scoped only to those types of declarations. It's a very low-level provider that Angular uses to create declarations with a view, and for that reason it's able to be injected into them -- and since services are also an `@Injectable`, the Angular DI hierarchy handles them separately, so the `Renderer2` is not available in their hierarchy.

To sum that up, `Renderer2` is available to `declarations` in a module. but not `providers`. `declarations` are instances and need templates attached, but `providers` are singletons and a template doesn't make much sense to them.

Using the `RendererFactory` would be the only way to *directly* inject a `Renderer2` into a service.

While I think your concern for not creating another instance of `Renderer2` is valid, check out this comment on [the Angular repo:](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17824#issuecomment-353239017)

> `rendererFactory.createRenderer(null, null)` would help, if no
>   (concrete) parameters passed, it will just return the default renderer
>   without create a new one. (sic)

So, using `RendererFactory2.createRenderer(null, null)` would just return the default `DomRenderer`. The factory exists to give the ability to create a *custom* renderer, and thankfully Angular is well-maintained enough to not create a duplicate `DomRenderer` if the factory is called.

So, just inject `RendererFactory2` into the service and get the default `Renderer2` from it.

Also, **thank you** for knowing that the `Renderer` is important in Angular and working so hard to use it. There are far too many people that go directly to DOM manipulation.

Comment: Thank you so much for the insight from the Angular sources and a core team member! Really knew something new from your answer. It's always wonderful to get answers based on first hand data!